# Maven module properties from another module

Tags: maven-2

I have a multi-module project. In one of the modules I'm generating classes from wsdl. In the pom of this module I need some properties of another module. (build.directory, outputDirectory etc)

It something like this possible?

```
${project.parent.module.0.build.directory}
```

I think I saw the above somewhere. Didn't bother testing it because doing `module.0` would mean it's dependent on the order in which modules are declared in the parent pom.

Is there a elegant way of doing what I want?

Comment: I think you're breaking maven's goal if you do that. Each module should be independent OR declare it's dependencies. What you're trying to do goes against this assumption. I suggest you to rethink how you're breaking up the modules, as the problem is potentially there.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. Thanks for the heads up. The problem is that this project is already beyond that. Every module is already coupled to one another by how it uses classes from other modules. If you take one module out... seems like modules are there just for show.

Comment: Why do you need the properties from an other module? If you are in the WSDL module you can generate the classes etc. within this modules and the result is a jar which can be used by other modules as a dependency. Or do you mean the properties ${build.outputDirectory} which are defined for every module by it's own. So you don't need others.

Comment: After the generation i will get 2 packages. One package I have to move in one module and the other in another module, this with maven copy resources. That's why I need propeties like outputDirectory and basedir of the modules. And yes I mean the properties in the pom.xml of each module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to have a parent. Define the properties in there and then simply use that as the parent in your other modules. That way you can easily share the properties across your modules.

Comment: indeed! i made a property in parent. `moduleX_target_output`. then used that in the modules and in the copy resource plugin. it's pretty clean. if I ever change that path I just change the property.

Answer (score 0):

Maven doesn't provide this kind of access. You could use [Groovy via GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) to parse the other pom as XML and get at what you want.